# Publishing DLL built in Release Mode but with debug=true

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, compilation, publishing

If you build and publish an ASP.NET web **application** in Release mode, does the `debug="true"` in the following web.config line ***in the development environment*** make any difference?

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="vb" debug="true" />
```

Obviously you would **always** have `debug="false"` on the production server - that is not in question.

My question is whether I should be setting `debug="false"` when I build the DLL's for publishing to the production system.

At the moment I don't, as it's a [PITA](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=PITA) to have to remember to change it between `true` for development and `false` for release.  I'm hoping the answer is "it makes no difference".

(I'm using Visual Studio 2010 with .NET 4.0 - the solution contains both VB.NET and C# projects, due to legacy reasons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [the following article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/11/Don_1920_t-run-production-ASP.NET-Applications-with-debug_3D001D20_true_1D20_-enabled.aspx) about the importance of running `debug="false"`

Excerpt:

> [Keeping the debug="true"] causes a number of non-optimal things to happen including:
>
> 1) The compilation of ASP.NET pages takes longer (since some batch
>   optimizations are disabled)
>
> 2) Code can execute slower (since some additional debug paths are
>   enabled)
>
> 3) Much more memory is used within the application at runtime
>
> 4) Scripts and images downloaded from the WebResources.axd handler are
>   not cached

---

After freefaller's remark i'd like to add that the configuration value is not important at the time of publishing, only at the time of running. So you could compile your assembly in release mode with debug="true" and deploy it with debug="false" without any problem. The parameter only acts on runtime configuration

Comment: Thanks @Samy, I'm reading it now.  Unfortunately your excerpt is about leaving the `debug="true"` on the production environment.  I've made it pretty clear in my question I'm talking about having `debug="true"` in the development environment.  Please read the question carefully, as I specifically made that clear on purpose

Comment: In fact, the entire article is talking about the flag in the production environment - therefore it is entirely **NOT** what I was asking for

Comment: @freefaller I don't think that the distinction is important; I think that it's better to be aware of the implications since you could legitimately want to run debug="false" on your dev environment (for example if you're measuring execution time, or want to have an idea of your app throughput). All in all, it makes a difference on the dev environment but you may not care about it on this platform, it's up to you :)

Comment: I see what you mean, and i edited the answer. I was too broad in my first answer :p

Comment: OK, thanks @samy.  Do you have any evidence (MSDN, official blog) to back up `The parameter only acts on runtime configuration`?

Comment: The msdn states that the configuration element in the web.config is used by asp.net to compile applications: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0%28v=vs.85%29.aspx . Since your assembly is already compiled it is not recompiled by ASP.Net and this parameter is not applicable to it

Comment: If the configuration element is "used by asp.net to compile applications" that would suggest that the attribute on the **development** environment **will** have an effect on the resultant DLL's.  That is what I've been trying to ask all along... and therefore the link you've just sent actually contradicts your answer

Comment: Asp.Net compiles some assemblies dynamically if you deploy code to the webserver, not precompiled assemblies. If you deploy a compiled assembly asp.net won't recompile it. If you deploy code (for example codefiles backing your aspx/ascx files) it will be recompiled on the server regardless of what parameter you have on your dev box. Ergo the value of the debug flag on your dev box at the time of building is not relevant. Unless you deployed dynamically built assemblies. Do you?

Comment: When you say "used by asp.net to compile applications"... are you talking about the compilation of the DLL's, or when the application is compiled on the production server by IIS?

Comment: Ahhhh... I think we've realised the confusion at the same time.  You **are** talking about the compilation that happens within IIS when you run the application for the first time (or any changes happen to files within the application).  That make sense now!!

Comment: Yes, the dynamic compilation by IIS of code resources (which i wouldn't really recommend): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure there is much you can do about it... from what I can tell, the dynamic compilation is always going to happen on web applications, independent of whether you use compiled DLL's or not

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between the compilation model of the assemblies and the debug mode of the ASP.NET application.

The assemblies in release mode allow the compiler to make optimizations to make the code faster and in general to consume less resources.

In opposite, the `<compilation debug="true" />` makes the application slow and consume more memory, in general all the disadvantages reported in the answer above.

Answer (score -1):

I think the VS will not take the value of debug attribute of the compilation tag in web.config when programmer rebuild the project.
I left the value of debug attribute as "debug" when I rebuild my project with the Configuratoin=release. And then I download the the utility [.NET Assembly Information](http://assemblyinformation.codeplex.com/) to check the output of my build. I find that those dlls are all "release" !!